# Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$uri

Tags: codeigniter, upload

Here is my config/upload.php code:

```
if($this->uri->segment(2)=='addPlace'){
    $config[upload_path] = './uploads/place_pic/';
    $config[allowed_types] = 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png';
}
elseif($this->uri->segment(2)=='addPack'){
    $config[upload_path] = './uploads/package_pic/';
    $config[allowed_types] = 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png';
}
```

after run my project it shows:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
```

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$uri

Filename: config/upload.php

Line Number: 2

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\project_tour_city\application\config\upload.php
Line: 2
Function: _error_handler

Comment: add this code in helper and define `$CI = &get_instance();` then call `$CI->uri->segment(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use as its not getting instance of class

```
$this->CI->uri->segment('2')
```

Comment: Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$CI

Comment: `<?php $CI =& get_instance(); ?>` write this line before use

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest you autoload the URI resource

Comment: can u describe how add autoload uri resource , is this correct :

$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'text' , 'uri');

Answer (score 0):

> You can Change Like This

You have to get ci master class

```
$ci =& get_instance();
// after you use $ci instead of $this
if($ci->uri->segment(2)=='addPlace'){
    $config[upload_path] = './uploads/place_pic/';
    $config[allowed_types] = 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png';
}
else if($ci->uri->segment(2)=='addPack'){
    $config[upload_path] = './uploads/package_pic/';
    $config[allowed_types] = 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png';
}
```